# What is WUBI?How does it work?

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

Which process does it use to install Ubuntu inside Windows?