# Is there any way to dual boot Windows 7 and Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Just wandering if there is any way to dual boot my windows 7 OS with Lubuntu, as I have a netbook, and don't want to loose windows, but want a faster OS.
Thanks in Advance,
Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? Make some space in another partition using a partitioning tool (gparted) and install Lubuntu there!

Comment: Can you give me instructions on how to do this please? I'm quite new to Ubuntu & Linux.