# Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

I want to download ubuntu as a second operating system for my laptop. I have windows 7 as my current operating system. I was wondering if I downloaded ubuntu onto my laptop would it erase windows 7 and everything in it? How could I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: No, it won't erase Windows, and your documents will be safe. But, as always, it pays to make a backup before doing anything major like this and saves pain later. Go ahead with the Live CD and install it on a new partition. There will always be someone here who can help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the Windows Ubuntu Installer (full instructions and download here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows).

This will keep your Windows 7 installation and files safe and will allow you to test Ubuntu by dual-booting.