# Can I install Ubuntu on My Windows 7

Tags: installation, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

I want to install Ubuntu. Is it safe to dual boot my computer with Windows 7 and Ubuntu?
If yes, please send me the information on how to do that.

Comment: Yes, its safe.  Take a look at [DualBoot/Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very safe. You will have to dual boot your system.
[Visit this for how to install it.](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony)
[This video can help you in this.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HANcetKsqc)

Comment: Can u give me a video ..How to do that...While installing ubuntu will i get the option for single boot or dual boot

Comment: wait I will try! and then I will update the answer