# Dual boot-windows 7 and ubuntu

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

I have windows 7 installed on my laptop, i want to install ubuntu 12.10 without losing windows. is it possible that during boot up, it gives me an option to chose how i want to boot after installing both the operating systems

for those of you who have tried dual booting

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please take a look at the following question [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Answer (score 1):

That is the default behaviour of Ubuntu 12.10.  During Ubuntu installation, simply select the option "Install alongside Windows" and Ubuntu will leave your windows partition alone and prompt you which OS to use on your next boot.

Comment: wow! thanx n just one more thing, will my wifi n bluetooth work as normal?