# How to Dual Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

So firstly I tried to install Ubuntu, from the website to run alongside Windows.  Went through Wubi etc.  Asked me if I wanted to try or Install, I selected install.  I selected option to run alongside Windows 7 but when it was partitioning it failed and I only had the fresh install as an option as probably Windows became corrupt then?

So I installed Windows again, ran Ubuntu from the livecd, went into gpartition, didn't really know what I was doing but anyhow, resized a partition which was 698gb, one was 100mb, I guessed CD drive.  Gparted said it was gonna take three hours, so I took that for meaning Windows was corrupt again.

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the steps in the [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) site. It has the steps to follow, along with some extra information you should keep in mind; for instance, it is a lot better to install Windows first, then Ubuntu.

Also, if you need to resize your Windows partition, make sure to defragment the drive in Windows first -- this will improve your results. You may also want to resize your Windows partition using Windows first. You can find more about that in this [How To Geek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/).