# Dual boot Windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

So I hava a TOSHIBA laptop (64 bit) with Windows 7 Home Premium. First I downloaded wubi.exe and I installed it to my laptop. The only problem with this when I start Ubuntu I always get an error: Prefix is not set.The ubuntu boot up succesfully after 1 minute but it is very slow. 
So I want to reinstall ubuntu from a CD. I burnt a Windows 7 Home Premium (english version) iso for a Verbatim DVD-R and an Ubuntu 12.04 (desktop edition) (amd64) iso for a Sony CD-R.
Okay I'm a beginner. Please anyone write me the method step by step: how to dual boot Windows 7 with ubuntu 12.04 
I have the Installation disks, what is the step 2?

Comment: You'll find a complete guide on setting up a Windows/Ubuntu dual boot here http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows

Comment: It's recommended not to use wubi, but allocate a separate partition for Ubuntu (this can be done from the installer CD or USB).

Answer (score 0):

First install a clean Windows 7, and then follow these steps for your dual boot setup with Ubuntu 12.04:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/

or

http://handytutorial.com/step-by-step-beginners-guide-installing-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Comment: So I'll do this: 1. Set BIOS to boot from a CD/DVD

Comment: If you think this answers your question, please mark it to "accept this answer". Thanks!