# Windows Application with .NET through PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit | Beginner needs help!

Tags: 12.04, installation, wine, playonlinux

## What do I want to do?

Run this software in Ubuntu 12.04: Achieve Planner by Effexis (http://www.effexis.com/achieve/AchievePlanner19Download.htm).

## What have I tried so far?

- Installed PlayOnLinux through Software Center
- (Tried to install .NET.  Did not work b/c of 64bit.  Did research, then moved on to the following steps.)
- Installed Wine 1.7 and 1.6 (32bit) within PlayOnLinux using "Tools/Manage Wine Versions"
- Installed .NET 1.1 (required by Achieve Planner) using the "Install" window's "Install a non-listed program" option.
- Installed Achieve Planner the same way.

## Where am I now?

Unable to launch Achieve Planner, and unable to interpret the error messages in the log file.

## Background Info

- Ubuntu 12.04 64bit
- Acer Desktop M3640 | Intel® Core™2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz x 4 | ATI Radeon HD 3650 | 3GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a [bug report](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17184) for this on the WineHQ bug tracker. While wine can run many Windows Applications, it can not run everything yet. It may still be awhile until you can run Achieve Planner on linux. I recommend that you [dual boot Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223161/dual-boot-windows-7-with-ubuntu-12-04-lts) or [run Windows in a Virtual Machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box-in-ubuntu-12-04) until then.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, and thank you for pointing me towards that bug report.  The last time I ran Achieve under Linux was about six years ago (back then successfully).

The bug description you refer to does not seem to describe what I am experiencing.  No mention of any "dll" in my logs.

(I wish I could copy the log info somehow.  So far all I manage to get is screenshots.)

I tried installing "dotnet20" as suggested in the last post on the bug report page, but I could not install it.  PlayOnLinux gave me a message about it not working in a 64bit environment.

I am confused about...

Comment: ...that, since I thought I had installed a 32bit version of Wine within PlayOnLinux, and then chosen that version.

As you can probably tell, I am quite green when it comes to Wine and/or PlayOnLinux.  I actually chose to try with PlayOnLinux, because it seemed to be the easiest way.

So maybe I am just stuck with a 64bit version of Wine?

*Confused*

Comment: Comment 4 on that bug report page says: 

"winetricks dotnet20 + running the program works"

Does using Winetricks interfere with using PlayOnLinux?

Comment: (By the way: neither dual boot nor a Virtual Machine seem attractive or sensible for the use case for this computer.  So it's up to me to figure out how to make Achieve work here.)

Comment: @Joshua [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231587/installing-dotnet-2-0-on-64-bit-machine) might help you with installing "dotnet20" in a 64bit environment.

Comment: Thank you for that link!  I just tried to go that way, but I did not get very far.  This is what I got:

`joshua@acer-M5640-M3640:~$ WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.win32 winecfg
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/joshua/.win32'
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: `p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.`

Comment: `err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot`

Comment: `fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0xebe8cc, overlapped 0xebe8b0): stub
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
wine: configuration in '/home/joshua/.win32' has been updated.
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Any idea what could be wrong?  I could not install dotnet20 (I tried), because it still seems to be 64bit.