# Install (side-by-side with windows) & uninstall ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

I'm looking for way to install it alongside the windows and at the same time also looking for "how to" uninstall ubuntu (in case I need to get things done quickly as I'm not used to ubuntu and in case I dislike ubuntu).

BTW, I have preinstalled windows 7 (64 bit) on my laptop (HP ProBook 4331s) and wonder will it be okay to install ubuntu side-by-side??
I also make my USB bootable disk ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit, is it ok when mine is windows 7 64 bit?

Thank you
Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Do a bit of search on Ask Ubuntu, you would get all your answers. For your first question about how to dual-boot, look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/1366/114818

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu, it should give you an option to install side by side. To delete, you just need to delete the partition that Ubuntu is installed on and then. If you are using MBR and not GPT, you also need to fix your boot loader. Before you install, make sure you have a recovery CD for Windows in case you break anything.

[image]