# How do I install Ubuntu allong side an existing Windows 7?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome

I have a 600GB hard disk which has three partitions `C`, `D` and `E` in Windows 7.

Windows 7 is installed on the `C` drive.

Now I want to install Ubuntu on `E` drive. How do I do this?

Is it a good idea to install with Wubi?

BTW, is it possible to use GNOME instead of the Unity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Live-CD of Ubuntu to install it. In the partition-menu you have to format your drive E to a linux Filesystem like ext4 (standard).

Ubuntu will install a boot-loader (GRUB) and add your windows installation to it. At startup you can choose which OS you want to boot.

Wubi is possible but not necessary in your setup.

This may help yout to install gnome3:
[How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So does the system installed by wubi have any performance problem with that of installed with a Live-cd?

Comment: Yes but its only a little.  With Wubi a Virtual file is created inside windows so there is a slight overhead in file access.  If you are sure you want to keep Ubuntu I would recommend a dual-boot install as not only will it be slightly faster.  Windows will be less likely to break Ubuntu since they are on separate partitions.

Comment: Thanks.  BTW,my computer have a memory of 8G,so which is better,i386 or amd64? I will do some j2ee/android/ruby development.

Comment: If you want to use the full ammunt of 8 GB RAM you must use the amd64 Version. x86 supports only up to 4 GB RAM.

Comment: There is more information in this question [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose) but unless you have some odd hardware which may not be supported by 64-bit yet I would go with 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your E disk
2. if you have a u-disk,Download live-CD iso file, use the Win32DiskImager.exe tool to make a boot disk.
3. set BIOS with u-disk 1 Priority。
4. after power up ubuntu， click install ubuntu which on the desktop。
5. In the partition-menu ,choose manaul setup.
   alway I use 10G to mount /, The rest of the disk to mount /$(you can name it yourself)