# "error: no such partition, grub rescue>" How do I fix this?

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot

I had a dual boot with windows 7 and ubuntu 12, and I deleted the ubuntu partitions, along with GRUB 2. Now i get this error and can't boot to windows.

I have a bootable usb with ubuntu.

Will simply installing ubuntu restore GRUB and fix the problem?

(I know it can be done with the ubuntu live CD without installing it, but i want to know if installing it will fix the problem.)

Comment: Do you want to install Ubuntu? Do you want to boot into Windows?

Comment: I want to have Ubuntu and dual boot with windows, as i have had previously.

Comment: But you *only* have Windows 7 **installed now**, right? And you can't even boot it, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, I have windows installed, and I can't boot because GRUB replaced the thing that boots windows, and i deleted GRUB.

Comment: If you want to install Ubuntu as dual boot with Windows 7, then [follow this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/1366/62483)

Comment: I've already seen those. My question is, do I have to do those things, even if I want to install Ubuntu? Will GRUB install automatically? I think I made that clear in the brackets.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've got nothing to lose if i try, anyway.