# Can't install Ubuntu on VAIO T13 (Window 7)

Tags: vaio

I've tried to install Ubuntu on my VAIO T13 (Ivy Bridge) Windows 7 laptop using windows installer but it doesn't work. After the system restarts, it said that I don't have the root folder and advised me to change in the partition (which I don't understand)

What should I do next?

P.S.

1) I've read this solution but I don't understand
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2127699

2) I'm very new to Linux, so may I have a bit detailed process please

Thank You

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Installing from within Windows using the Windows installer (WUBI.EXE) has some problems and is not supported in the recent versions of Ubuntu. Consider a full dual boot installation. See [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows) for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be helpful, but I had to open my bios and set anti theft to disabled before I could install Ubuntu. Before I did that Ubuntu could not detect the hard drive.