# Upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: upgrade

I have installed Ubuntu 10 using a windows installer and then upgraded to 12, recently. I got to hear about the experiences of others of the 13.04 and was eager to upgrade and somehow that wasn't possible so wanted to check if there is any procedure which I overlooked.
I have netbook atom processor N450 @ 1.66 GHz, 512 kb cache, 1 GB memory.

Answer (score 1):

Windows installation using WUBI was dropped from 12.10 to 13.04 as a means of concentrating development effort. There is no method to upgrade such an installation now, nor will there be.

If you want Ubuntu 13.04 or later versions alongside your Widows-Installation you will have to install it by booting from a Live Medium such as a DVD. You can then copy the `/home` folder and other files to the new installation.

If you want detailed instructions take a look at this question:

[How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1366/107450)