# Ubuntu on Windows 7

Tags: windows

I have a computer with Windows 7 and want to install Ubuntu and start asking me which operating system to start on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

just check out this page. it shows how to dual boot win 7 and ubuntu from one hdd or from 2 hdd etc.

[Dual-boot](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/10/11/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-on-a-pc-with-uefi-hardware/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is too use the [Wubi-installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=wubi&bits=&release=lts). This will install Ubuntu alongside Windows automatically.

Make sure you have enough space on your Hard-Disk. I made a second partition and installed Ubuntu on there.

The more difficult way is to install Ubuntu Manually which would require a bit more work than the wubi installer. And If your unlucky It wont work. If you have Hardware that support UEFI then your gona have a hard time installing Ubuntu alongside Windows.

For more Info check out this post: [How To Dual-Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)
If your creating a bootable stick follow the instruction here: [How to create a bootable stick in windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
If your using a CD/DVD follow these steps: [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)

Note: the description in the post above is for Ubuntu 11.10 however the steps are basically the same so you can just download the newest Ubuntu and follow the steps provide in the post.

Comment: Though it should be noted that Wubi is deprecated in the future.