# How to dual boot ubuntu with Windows 7 without losing my files?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I downloaded the Ubuntu-13.04-Desktop-i386.iso (794.00Mo) file and burned it into a DVD of 4.7GB with a very low speed of burning.

Anyway the OS was bootable when I put the DVD the Ubuntu Installer appears it asks to choose language , try Ubuntu and Install Ubuntu.I chose Install Ubuntu. An OS detection and formatting disc step appears and it gives me options, install Ubuntu with Windows 7 , replace windows by Ubuntu ..etc.I choose Install Ubuntu with Windows 7 and a partition appears;

***I don't really understand how to proceed?***

I have a hard disc partitioned to 2 parts `C:\ and D:\` .

- C:\ size is 39.0 GB
- the D:\ is 35.4 GB
- the free space on C:\ is 22GB/39GB

I have important files on D:\ drive.
Please how do I install Ubuntu 13.04 with Windows 7 without loosing D:\ files and without loosing Windows 7
My Windows is : Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit fr
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options, which are widely explain here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Install_Ubuntu

First, is the simplest.

If you take the another option, manual partitioning, possibly you've to learn more about partitioning and linux file systems (For this matter, you can have a look to this [How to Partiotion manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition)).
But you'll be able to assign the size you want to each partitions components for ubuntu.

In this other link you can view an step-by-step installation for the same purpose:
[How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't know what you are doing, leave that part alone and go on to the next step. The default settings are fine unless your laptop has a *very* small amount of space left. What this step does is has you allocate space to each operating system. As long as you don't give to little space to Ubuntu or (more likely) Windows, you will be fine. Here, it is safest just to go to the next step.

I hope this helps and have fun with Ubuntu (I know you'll love it!)

Comment: ok thank you very much for your answers :) it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

boot into win7 and insert ubbuntu DVD ,and just start the setup :) 
ubuntu creates a VHD kinna file on c:/ and installs itself in it leaving both partitions unchanged, and finally it just replaces win nt bootloader with GRUB :)

Hope that helps

Comment: ok but when it replaces windows nt bootloader i'll still be able to get access to windows right?

Comment: @YoucefStrike Ubuntu does not exactly replace the Windows NT bootloader. The way this works is that Ubuntu replaces the Windows bootloader entry in the Master Boot Record with its own GRUB2 entry. The Windows bootloader is still there and Windows is still bootable. In fact, the way GRUB2 boots Windows is that it chainloads the Windows bootloader. As a result, you should have no trouble with Ubuntu overwriting Windows.