# install problems at the "expanding" section

Tags: system-installation

I have an HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook with an AMD AE-35200M APU with Radeon HD Graphics 1.60 GHz. I has 8 gigs of ram and a 64-bit operating system.

I have only one storage device and I already have windows 7 installed. I am attempting to run Ubuntu on my computer without having to uninstall windows. The steps I took so far are as follows: I went to the official Ubuntu downloader and burned an installation disk. I then ran the disk to begin installation. A prompt window came up asking for a name and password along with a few other things that I left at default. It began installing and made it to the part mentioned above and then stopped.

Everything goes well until the install got to the "expanding" section. It has been on this screen for five hours, and the progress bar has not moved.  I have retried this twice with no success. So, can I assume something is wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide details about the steps you are following for installing Ubuntu and if you are dual-booting. Please, [edit] the question for this.

Comment: Add information about your PC model/hardware to the question, please. Also read: [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1366/159545)

Comment: I have an HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook with an AMD AE-35200M APU with Radeon HD Graphics 1.60 GHz. I has 8 gigs of ram and a 64-bit operating system. And thanks for the link, I will read it over and see if it helps!