# bootmgr is missing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

How do I setup the file system and partitions to dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu?

Bootmgr is missing, and the OS cannot be found. I've looked at a few utilities, like UBCD, but they are somewhat technical and I don't wish to mess up my system any more than it already is.

Comment: You may want to view the page OR10N listed for help as to fixing your bootmgr issues. Flagging as duplicate of [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1366/107590)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry your installation didn't work out. However, this is not a Windows Support forum.

If you want to fix your bootmgr, please take a look at this how-to: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/bootmgr-is-missing.htm

One more thing, I would highly recommend you to boot your system using an Ubuntu LiveCD and make a backup of everything important.