# Install Ubuntu alongside Windows?

Tags: windows

I want to install Ubuntu for first time.
if I install ubuntu alongside Window 7 or 8 there will be no problem ?

Comment: God only knows. I mean, no one know if the will be a problem, but it should not be. See this post: [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1366/62483) and [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 System UEFI Supported](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

As Lucio said, only God knows, though you shouldn't expect to face any problems along the way.

If this is the first time you install Ubuntu, consider WUBI install, so you can get familiar with the installation process.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend WUBI any more. In fact, it is not supported since Raring.

Comment: I never did the WUBI install, just seemed to me easier for first starters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer because there are many different variables involved. Every system is different. In my experience Windows 7 is very easy to dual boot. Windows 8 can be a bit more taxing if your system uses UEFI. However nothing is impossible :)

Consider giving it a try first via usb or dvd:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

If that goes well you should be able to dual boot very easily. The same USB / DVD install process will guide you through how to do it and should take care of most of the process for you.

Best of luck.