# Installing 12.04 from 12.10 with black screen issue

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, live-usb, screen

I recently upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 and now have an issue with a black screen upon booting. Im having a lot of trouble with this issue and I dont care to fix it anymore. I still have the usb drive that I used to install 12.04 from windows 7. can somebody please, please run me through how to get back to using 12.04 it would be much appreciated.

Comment: My issue is that installing the OS is not the same in ubuntu as it is in windows. I dont know how to install 12.04 from the usb in bios.

Comment: I will link to two questions that may help you, but If you installed Ubuntu the first time it should not be an different this time, other than the installer will find your Ubuntu partition and ask you if you want to "Replace Ubuntu 12.10 with Ubuntu 12.04" if you select that one it will do so but to repeat-IT WILL OVERWRITE ALL YOUR FILES AND PROGRAMS IN UBUNTU. the already answered questions that should help you are [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Comment: One other note, in case you didn't know. Getting your computer to boot into the USB varies by system, it could be `Esc` but will most likely be `F8-F12`.  You should be able to tell this by checking the BIOS screen that comes up when the computer is booting. It should be in the upper or lower right corner of the screen.