# will reinstalling ubuntu mess with grub?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

My computer has windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 on a dual boot with grub, and I want to upgrade to 13.04 with a fresh install and grow the partition.

the method I want to follow is this one:

- Go to the windows disk management and format swap and Ubuntu
  partition
- grow partition with disk management (from 30 GB to 120 GB)
- boot on bootable usb stick install Ubuntu 13.04 along side windows 7 like in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

My questions are:

- will this mess with grub?(more unusable boot options or something)
- is it safer to use windows disk manager application for formatting
  the partitions instead of gparted?
- imagine I can't install Ubuntu after I formatted the partitions, will
  this make my machine unbootable? how do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

> will this mess with grub?(more unusable boot options or something)

Probably not, GRUB is generally pretty good at working after an upgrade or similar

> is it safer to use windows disk mannager application for formating the partitions instead of gpart?

Most definitely **not**. Windows Disk Management cannot create `ext4` or `swap` partitions as you would need to run Ubuntu. You would be better off using GParted from the LiveCD when you install Ubuntu or even the partitioner in the Ubuntu installer

> imagine I can't install ubuntu after I formatted the partitions, will this make my machine unbootable? how do I solve this?

You can use Boot Repair from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu)