# Unable to hibernate using sudo pm-hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 7. The hibernate does not work from command prompt using `sudo pm-hibernate`, whereas the suspend works fine using `sudo pm-suspend`.

What could be the problem? How do I solve this?

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 100.0 GB, 100030242816 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 12161 cylinders, total 195371568 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe0779162

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   195366464    97683201    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Out put of cat `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /               ext4    loop,errors=remount-ro 0       1
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk none            swap    loop,sw         0       0
```

Output of `sudo blkid -o full -s UUID`:

```
/dev/loop0: UUID="59cea3d6-37da-4a92-8ccf-f500a76750ff" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="A4D4A3CAD4A39CD4"
```

Comment: Edit you question with the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid -o full -s UUID`.

Comment: Done now... @Jobin

Comment: Are you sure you have pasted the complete output of `sudo fdisk -l`? I can't see any `ext4` partitions, and that is highly impossible.

Comment: Yes I have rechecked again, even I am now wondering. But, that is the case. Maybe, since I loaded UBUNTU from Windows, it is loaded as a OS under Windows, hence, it is only showing one hard disk persay. @Jobin

Comment: How did you install ubuntu? wubi?

Comment: Yes, correct. @Jobin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernation is not supported for [wubi installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi). You will have to reinstall Ubuntu as a dual booted OS and then create a swap partition to enable hibernation.

**Refer:**

- [How to install Ubuntu without removing windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Comment: Thanks a lot. After partitioning my hard disk and installing 13.10, I had to do the changes suggested in the bug report to enable Hibernate. Now it functions as it is supposed to. Thanks a tonne. @Jobin