# How do I run install Ubuntu 13.10 and keep windows at the same time?

Tags: system-installation

I burned the iso onto the disk and ran it. Which option do I choose?

These are the only options I have:
-Erase disk and install Ubuntu

-Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for installation.

-Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation.

-Something else.

Comment: why don't you select and try Something else!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

[Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

[Install Ubuntu with the Windows installer (Wubi)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)

Or go to answered question: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Choose something else, and then manually select the partition you wish to install on.

[Need advice installing Ubuntu on 2nd storage drive for windows 7 computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430036/need-advice-installing-ubuntu-on-2nd-storage-drive-for-windows-7-computer)

Comment: Is there some relevance for the link you provided? The OP did not state that they are trying to install this on another drive nor that it was Windows 7 already installed. While the "something else" direction you offered is valid, your answer could be expanded to include more detail about what that entails.