# Will I lose all my files from XP OS if I install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I have a simple question.

I have a disc particion to C, D and E on my Windows XP and I want to install Ubuntu.

Will I lose all my files from D and E (it's like 50 gb, and I don't have an external HDD) when I install Ubuntu? Or the system while installing it offers me options to save my files somewhere or...?

Comment: Creating a separate ext4 partition for Ubuntu and choosing something else option during Ubuntu installation will keep your datas from deletion.

Comment: Please add more details about your hard disk partitions..

Comment: If you want to keep Windows (and even sometimes using Windows), see [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1366). You'd tell Ubuntu's installer to install *alongside* the current OS. If you want to get rid of your Windows system, then (assuming Windows is currently the only OS on the disk and you don't have any separate data partitions on the disk that you want to keep), you'd tell it to *use the entire disk* in which case your files in Windows will be destroyed (so, copy stuff off first). See also [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328).

Answer (score 0):

Ok you wont lose windows XP or your files when you use the installer for Ubuntu you need to select the option to custom the hard drive using G parted usually the install along side windows option will allow you to resize the drive if C: is big like at lest 20 GB make c: into 2 10GB an use the new 10gb partition to install the Ubuntu OS the good thing is Windows XP only needs 8gb partition to work and this will leave all your other files and drives in place and only change the boot C: windows xp drive 10gb is enough to install Ubuntu and have the swap partition and if will also allow you to duel boot with windows xp

Answer (score 0):

No you won't loose them.

If you want to dual-boot Ubuntu with XP,just choose to custom partition your hard disk and make a new ext4 partition for Ubuntu.

More details here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Alternatively, if you wish to replace XP, you can place Ubuntu in place of the present C: without affecting other partitions. Be sure to save your Documents, Pictures or any other important things from C: .

Welcome to Ubuntu!

Comment: Agreed. Removed that line, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

YES. You are more than likely to lose your files if you do not know what you're doing.

This is a rather advance topic. If you want to keep both OSes, then you want to do a dual boot system as explain by others. However, there is not guarantee that you won't lose your data. If you cannot do a backup and your files are important, then it is NOT safe.