# Changing the disk to partition when wanting to dual boot install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to install 14.04. The problem is quite simple: I get to the point where I must chose how much memory ubuntu should get. (The drag how much you want menu)

The **only** drive I can chose from is C which is running terribly low on memory (~10gigs) where as my D has over 500 free. The question is simple: How can I get the installer to let me chose D and not C ?

Edit: I am stuck on point 5 of the answer to this question [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Exit the Ubuntu installer and open gparted partition editor from dash. If it's not installed by default then run the below commands to install gparted.

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```
- Format your D drive into ext4 filesystem
- Now run the installer, choose something else option to install Ubuntu on the created ext4 partition.

Comment: I have 2 questions- 1) I should exit the installation but be on "try ubuntu"? 2) Will this installation cause data loss on D ?

Comment: I think the problems is installing it in Windows, the Ubuntu installer doesn't have a slider, the Windows one does, difference is having the Windows bootloader vs. grub. Maybe putting the installer in the D drive and trying to install it.

Comment: 1.yes, choose try Ubuntu option. 2. Yes, when you format D drive to ext4 filesystem, all your datas in D drive will be lost. So backup all the datas in D drive before formatting.

Comment: @ubuntu1up but we can resize the partitions through gparted.

Comment: @Avinash Raj, I know, but if Bloodcount is installing it in Windows, maybe the Windows bootloader will be a more comfortable option, then there isn't a deal with editing grub if Bloodcount wants Windows to boot first after the waiting period

Comment: _but if Bloodcount is installing it in Windows_ What's the meaning of this?

Comment: I am not too keen on losing my data. I will probably use wubi to get 12.04 and then distro upgrade (one way I see that I can install it on D without losing data) Note to self: Next time I reinstall windows, make a dedicated partition for ubuntu.

Comment: are you trying to install Ubuntu through wubi?

Comment: No, I am not. Last time (~an year ago) I did it with wubi and the installation went perfectly.

Comment: get into here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/boot-repair-problems-would-be-discussed-here