# Is it possible to turn the .ISO file into a .exe file?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, iso, executable, windows-vista

I've downloaded Trusty (14.04) and it's an .iso file. I knew what I had to do, I got a thingy to mount the image (Slysoft to be precise) and mounted the .iso and up came the Ubuntu thing running through what to do, so I restarted my machine and it didn't boot with ubuntu, instead it was the normal boot up. (I'm using Vista [the worst os ever made] to be clear). So, I gots to thinking maybe I could just convert the file into a .exe file and then install it through that, but is that possible? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, exe and iso are two different files. A exe is a windows executable, while iso is an image of a disk. If you want to replace vista with ubuntu, plug the dvd (usb) in and at boot press a key, typically it says for a second on the screen which key to press to go into the boot menu. From there you choose the usb or dvd and voila, Ubuntu boots up. Then just follow the installation instructions.

**UPDATE**: Just use wubi, it's in the iso file. This will only allow you to try ubuntu on your windows partition.

Comment: I can't do that though, thats why I need to change it or do something else, when I restart (because Ubuntu says that's what will make it run) I do the whole boot option thingy and then it just runs Vista instead and the cycle continues

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Are you sure you've done everything correctly?

Comment: Very sure, I've followed the installation guide to the dot, not to sound like snarky or anything like that :)

Comment: Hmm, nope. Something is wrong with the fact that the bios doesn't load the disk, although perhaps you've done something wrong with burning it. I used LiLi live linux... something

Comment: It's just that the bios boots the first drive that has a bootable system, that's why it defaults to windows

Comment: I think you may be right about the dvd burner thingymabob, I had to use my auntie's so no idea what it was called, though I shall try and track down this lili live linux thingy :)

Comment: Here: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ very simple to use (giving that you're burning it on an USB)

Comment: was just about to say I found it ahahah, yeah, jsut need a USB now, but thanks for the help :) if it goes awry then my lappy probably has some sort of hardware issue

Comment: Nope, no hardware issue possible here. Windows boots, Ubuntu should boot

Comment: And I seriously recommend using LiLi, I've tried 3 versions of Ubuntu, arch linux and kali linux with it.

Comment: Hmm.. then it has to be that the dvd burned incorrectly, I'll buy a USB and then put it onto there and fingers crossed it'll work before Windows makes me shoot myself haha :) thanks for your help! :D

Comment: I meant not possible as highly unlikely. Best try it with an USB and make sure the bios is all right.

Comment: OK :) what size USB is reccommended?

Comment: Well last time I used 4GB, yes that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not. An disk image (iso) contains more than just an executable.

The best to do is to make an live usb stick (or cd) and install it while vista is shut down.

To create a live usb stick, you can follow [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to create an live ubuntu USB or just burn the disk image in an CD/DVD. Then proceed with the [installation of ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows).