# problem with ubuntu instalation on my Dell Workstation

Tags: 14.04

After installation is over it can't load it shows the error like "No boot device found.Press any key to reboot the machine."

I can install Redhat and windows but not Ubuntu(12.04.1,12.04.2,13.10,14.04,14.04.1and14.04.2) our system model is Dell Precision Tower 7810

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a Dell Precision Tower 7810 but I was finally able to install and run Ubuntu 16.04 on the workstation.

**Change the following things on BIOS setup:**

Disable safe boot.

Change SATA operation to AHCI.

**Creating the bootable device (Pendrive):**

Download Rufus and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS iso in a Windows machine.

Open "Rufus and select GTP partition scheme for UEFI computer". This will need a functional internet connection as the program will download two files from the internet.

Now boot from the bootable drive and install Ubuntu on the machine.
You can check once after installing the OS if the system is booting or directly run the "Boot Repair" program in live mode after the installation.
After the process is complete reboot the machine, it will detect the Ubuntu installation now.

You can try this process with 14.04 version also.

Answer (score 0):

Form a short google research I guess your system uses UEFI, right?

I had exactly the same problem with a Dell XPS 13 2015. The reason for me was that no boot option/selections was set in the BIOS. Please make sure there is one called "ubuntu" or similar.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to add it manually so I ended up restoring the BIOS to default, enabling UEFI and SecureBoot and installing it again. Then the boot selection was set correctly and it worked. Not the smartest solution but it worth a try.

Comment: Thank you for your reply....I tried this it shows the error     "No bootable devices,                                           strike f1 to retry boot,                                         f2 for setup utility,                                         press f5 to run onboard diagnostics

Comment: Is in the BIOS under Boot Selections (or Options?) something set like "Ubuntu". And is there UEFI chosen instead of Legacy?

Comment: I tried both option when the boot list option - legacy is selected the error is " NoBoot device found.press any key to reboot the machine"

when the boot list option -UEFI is selected  the error is "
No bootable devices, strike f1 to retry boot, f2 for setup utility, press f5 to run onboard diagnostics

Comment: I looked it up and what I called Boot Selections can be found at "Boot Sequence" (at least at me). Is there an entry called "Ubuntu"? What I found out yesterday, when reinstalling my OS, was that I had to eject the installation medium before clicking the restart button at the end of the installation. Otherwise (when ejecting shortly after the begin of the boot process) the entry was erased. This seems to be a strange behaviour to me as well. Perhaps the same reason for your problem.
(I installed via usb-stick)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

Download this and format it for Ubuntu (any version cha want) from Windows OS and then boot from there and install :-)

Here's a guide: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/guide

I had the same problem and my machine was a custom built powerhouse and I asked a similar question and some guy referred me to that link and it's a lifesaver! Good luck :-)

Found the link to my other accounts question, read the comments on the accepted answer: [Is it possible to turn the .ISO file into a .exe file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509759/is-it-possible-to-turn-the-iso-file-into-a-exe-file)

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply Hugo!I tried this method but its not working .When I contact Dell persons they mentioned to do partition in my hard drive(hard drive 3x4TB). I tried that also but it shows the same error

Comment: The only thing I can think of is burning the iso image onto a disk and then change boot options to CD and fire away..

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install Ubuntu on my Dell XPS 13 and got this error too. I disabled secure boot and enabled legacy BIOS mode in the UEFI settings. Then I reinstalled Ubuntu and it worked.