# how to install ubuntu without deleting my other drives?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

i have tried 3 times to install ubuntu. but every time i dont know how deleted all my drives, along with system drive. how to install ubuntu without deleting those? i have 2 drives in my hard disk. 1 is dedicated for system. can anyone help?

Comment: Use "Somthing Else" option while installing from Disk.

Comment: easiest method: created unallocated space from your current operating system. Pick "something else" during installation and pick the unallocated partition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/22949) or [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1366/22949) or [“Install alongside” option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using “Something Else”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/163962/22949)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you have any Windows installation to your computer ?

If yes, you can partition it during Ubuntu installation.
You have to select "Something Else" when it asks you where to install Ubuntu.

Then, Ubuntu has a nice tool, with user friendly GUI to partition your hard disks.

Here is a screenshot of Ubuntu's partitioning tool -->

[image]