# Multiple operating systems on one computer

Tags: system-installation, windows

Can I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 on the same computer? If so, how do I do this? I want to be able to choose which operating system to boot up to when I turn on my computer.

Comment: Yes you can, read about it [here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows

Answer (score 0):

Ok your question is a little bit foggy. Could you please tell me the specs of your computer i.e hardisk space, model e.t.c also the current operating system installed on it.

Well a windows operating system is currently installed on it well it as simple as partioning your hard disk to make space for ubuntu, downloading your ubuntu iso , using Unetbootin to create a bootable Usb (USB has to to be at least 2GB) and installing the ubuntu iso image into the USB using Unetbootin. When that is done just restart your computer (while keeping the bootable usb you just created connected to your computer at during the whole process) , I dont know what your key is but just after the computer starts to boot up just press Escape (That's what i do anyways) select BIOS menu Navigate to where it says Boot Device or something like that ,make usb to be the first item on list, save and exit . It should boot you up to the Ubuntu setup . The installation of ubuntu should detect that you have Windows installed on you computer and ask you if it should be installed side-by-side or should delete windows and install ubuntu only (you should know what to choose).

When its done whenever you boot up it should ask you what OS you want to boot up to.

Edit How to partion your hard disk Visit http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309170.aspx

Comment: I am running a Windows 7 home premium desktop computer with2 GB RAM, 32 bit AMD Athlon 2 proscessor. It also says pwered by ASUS. enough information?

Comment: Ok cool i was right so if you follow my steps above everything should go by easy