# Install Ubuntu from usb-stick: Caught in endless-reboot loop

Tags: system-installation, usb-creator

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS using the following instructions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick

I sucessfully booted from the USB stick (installer boot menu -> install ubuntu) and clicked on the setup-icon on the Ubuntu Desktop. Everything goes fine until I select the option

> **Install Ubuntu inside Windows 7**

After I click "continue" Ubuntu reboots automatically and I end up where I started (the installer boot menu - no installation started as one might expect).

What am I missing here? Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: which iso did you use (i386 or amd64, desktop or server) and what architecture does the machine/CPU have? EFI or legacy bios boot?

Comment: thanks. amd64, desktop, and i have a 64bit amd-processor laptop. i dont know about efi or legacy, i just put USB at first place in the boot order.

Comment: I'm not sure about "Install Ubuntu inside Windows 7". I've seen that several times in question in AU, maybe it's a bug in the installer or a common misunderstanding of how multiboot installations work. Did you mean "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7"?

Comment: I am quite sure it said "Install Ubuntu inside Windows 7" but anyways its probably the same as "Install Ubunto alongside Windows 7". This option was described as installing Ubuntu while leaving Windows 7 intact such that I can choose the OS when booting.

Answer (score -1):

Am not sure what is "Install Ubuntu inside Windows 7" !

Check this two links:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2209033

[How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer, especially the "Answers & Apples" section