# Chances of Ubuntu breaking my PC?

Tags: 14.04

I've been using windows 7 on my HP Pavilion G6 for quite a while now, I've always wanted to install Ubuntu and have all the files on my USB Flash Drive after using Universal USB installer. My USB is a Cruzer Edge 4gb, and I just want to know the chances of it breaking (there is also no boot from usb option)

EDIT: Not sure if this is a problem, but I've installed it on virtualbox and it's really, really, really laggy.

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu from your USB or are you storing your files on the usb? Some BIOS's have disabled usb boot, go into boot options and enable it, if it doesn't boot...

Comment: Trying to install Ubuntu from a USB. I used universal usb installer for it.

Comment: does it boot at all or?

Comment: I haven't tried yet, I'm too afraid I might break something.

Comment: Ok, I will try soon, but I don't know how to partition the hard-drive, so I won't be able to do that.

Comment: It won't let me boot from USB, there is no options in boot devices, no "legacy boot" anywhere, I changed the boot order so ALL usb devices are above, It still boots into windows. I guess I have to give up trying to get Ubuntu :(

Comment: you most likely have to press a key for it to boot to the usb. I have to press f3, some has to press f5, try them or google your computer model.

Comment: It said nothing about a key, All I did was change the boot order so the USB options were on top. If this doesn't work, I'll try and run my Lubuntu DVD, But whenever I press "Install Lubuntu Alongside Windows 7", it says Restart, tells me to move installation media and boots back into Win7.

Comment: Have you looked at the link I posted?

Comment: Don't worry, you have no chance of breaking something by booting from an Ubuntu Live USB.

Answer (score 0):

1. The chances of Ubuntu damaging your computer hardware are negligible.
2. You can choose to “Try Ubuntu” before installing it. That way you can discover and research possible hardware driver issues.
3. What you should consider is the risk, that you accidentally delete your data while repartitioning¹ your drive(s) for an additional operating system. Stick to the [installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) or other [reliable²](https://askubuntu.com/a/92066/175814) [advice³](https://askubuntu.com/a/228069/175814), be careful, and back up your data!

The performance of virtual machines cannot be compared reasonably to that of natively running software. They're known to have poor (graphics) performance without proper configuration.

¹ Can be done with during installation. The installer will assist you. For details see the answers linked at ² and ³.

² for legacy BIOS

³ for UEFI BIOS

Comment: I have nothing to back up my data on, and I don't know how to partition.

Comment: You shouldn't proceed any further when you have no possibility to back up data. Regarding partitioning: http://askubuntu.com/q/343268/40581

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu installer is a robust piece of software, breaking thing with that is hard.

The "installer" has an "try ubuntu" option where an ubuntu experience is loaded directly in the RAM leaving the hdd untouched, and thus reducing the chance of breaking things to zero. This is a very useful and foolproof way of getting familiar with Ubuntu/linux, and you can always decide to get back to ol-Windows later.

So in short:

the installers chance of bricking your PC = tiny

the "try ubuntu" option chance of bricking your pc = zero

Comment: I would be very careful with such statements. While it may work for you without breaking things, other users may very well break their software or hardware in ways you don't expect. Also expect that users buy crappy hardware seemingly on purpose or don't know how to judge quality regarding Linux compatibility. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/ubuntu-installer-bug-wipes-partitions https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/

Answer (score 0):

It's not surprising your seeing things are laggy with VirtualBox. You're sharing resources between Windows and Ubuntu. You can change your settings to give more of your system over to the virtual machine but it's always going to be less powerful than running it exclusively on the machine