# Problem with installing the latest version of ubuntu

Tags: ati

As the title says, I am currently looking into duel booting ubuntu with windows. But as I download the latest version, I either come up with a blank screen from a disk, or an error after installing it from the website. Any answers and/or help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 8, you should follow this guide to install ubuntu.

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Comment: Sadly, I'm using a pirated version of Windows 7.