# HardDrive Partitions to install Ubuntu together with W7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I'm going to install Ubuntu 14 on my laptop. This is now my hardrive config:

[image]

- C: Windows
- D: Music, Photos, Documents, etc

I've two questions. After I get free space from D, which partitions I'll be create to install Ubuntu?

And second, all my data stored now in D, will be accesible from Ubuntu?

Thanks a lot, I'm a "Windows Boy" and i want to have a chance to Ubuntu!! Excuse me for my spelling.

**EDIT**

[image]

I need some more help here. I reduce C: in 20gb and get unallocated space. After this, I reduce D: n 68gb and I get free space inside this partition.

What i'm doing wrong? I cannot merge the unallocated space with the free space. what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: At minimum you'll create a partition to mount at / and perhaps a swap partition as well: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not (usually even can not) create any partitions for Ubuntu in Windows. Just give it a bit of unallocated space and the installer will set it up properly.

Inside the Ubuntu installer, you (or the installer automatically) will create a root partition (format as `ext4` and select: "Use as `/`") and a swap partition (format as `linux-swap`"). That is enough, you could even omit the swap partition (but it's *not* recommended to do so!).
You can also create a separate home partition (format usually as `ext4` and select: "Use as `/home`") for the users' personal data and configuration, which makes reinstalls and backups a bit easier. Otherwise that directory is included in your root partition `/`.

You will be able to mount and access all your NTFS partitions from Ubuntu, but the other way round, accessing Ubuntu's ext4 partitions from Windows, will not work. Note that writing files from both Windows and Ubuntu to the NTFS partitions might lead to permission problems...

Comment: Ok Thanks! I have a prendrie ready to give a shot. In a while I'll comment the results

Comment: Please, can you see the new information? I edit the post. Thanks!

Comment: You have to enlarge the extended partition (the dark green container where the D drive and the free space are located in) to cover up the unallocated space. Then you can move the D partition inside the container to the left and add the unpartitioned space which is now at the left of the free partition to that. I recommend you to use GParted from the Ubuntu live CD instead of Windows' integrated partitioning tool.

Comment: This procedure is secure? I mean, is there any chance that data loss?

Comment: There is always the chance of data loss when you do partitioning, but normally it's very unlikely unless you stop it during the process or anything else happens... A backup is always a good idea to make first, then you don't have to worry.