# Downloading Ubuntu after downloading Windows 10

Tags: windows, downloads

I regrettably installed Windows 10 and would now like to install Ubuntu. However the download for desktop says it is only for Win 7 or earlier.

Is there a link to download Ubuntu without having to uninstal Windows 10?

Many thanks

Alistair

Comment: Do you want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, or replace your Windows installation?

Comment: You probably are trying to install using wubi. It is not supported any more.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, unless you're planning on using WUBI ([which is no longer supported beyond Windows 7](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)) you should be able to just download any of ISO files and put it on a USB stick or DVD and go from there.

I haven't tested it myself, but it should work just fine and pretty much the same as it would for Windows 8/8.1.

The biggest thing you would have to do is to make sure you have empty space to install Ubuntu on. You can do that either from within Windows or by choosing the **Try Ubuntu** option when you boot the LiveUSB/LiveDVD and using GParted to resize the Windows partition.

For more information about how to install Ubuntu I would suggest you look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows). The second one may apply more to you because it's about installing Ubuntu without removing Windows.

Comment: Thank you all for your speedy help. I shall follow suggestions and will revert if still having problems Alistair