# Ubuntu Download Help

Tags: downloads, system

how can I download Ubuntu and also keep all my files saved to my laptop at the same time? I have a bunch of apps that I don't want to get deleted and I've already downloaded the iOS on my USB and before I do anything I need to know how I can download it without anything getting removed.

Comment: See [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu), [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows), and (if necessary) [“Install alongside” option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using “Something Else”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using) If none of that applies to your situation then please [edit] your question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Run the Live environment, and DO NOT INSTALL: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Otherwise, follow the links Eliah provided.

**Long Answer:**

Installing an OS can be a big deal; you can easily run into trouble either by your own mistake or by getting unlucky and the installer fails or messes something up. Then you may have to get into some really geeky troubleshooting, depending on how bad it is.

Ubuntu has been refined and is an attempt to make Linux easy and accessible for anyone. If you're willing to try that, then go ahead and install as they guide you to.

However, if you are this concerned already, and the many mistakes you made using technical terms were in fact from your best effort of explaining your problem, I warn you that you do not sound experienced enough to handle any issues that may come up, and I even fear you being prone to making an accident that can make you lose things.

**Recommendation:** If this is your only / main PC, don't install it; just run the Live environment to try it out. If you want to install it, do it on an older computer you don't care about.

If you're willing to risk it on your main PC, then **simply follow instructions carefully, exactly**, and go ahead! You SHOULD be fine, Ubuntu is pretty good, and you will never learn if you don't try! BUT, **always be safe**: back up your files, know how to re-install all the programs you want, etc., in case everything gets - or needs to be - wiped.

Comment: Okay thank you, I just have a bunch of skype convos that I do not want to get deleted and a lot of music and apps that take a long time to download... anyways I guess ill just buy a windows 10 activation key and activate windows. thanks again Rhoi

Comment: You're welcome! Regardless of whether you stay with Windows, use both Windows and Linux, or switch to Linux, you should have a backup plan since you never know when something will fail. That's the main issue, here; have another hard drive, have online storage, etc., to keep these things safe.

But definitely do try out Ubuntu. In time, maybe you can switch to it and not have to pay for Windows again. Applications are the only concern, since you have to check if what you want is available in Ubuntu or can be made to work with it.

Comment: @TaylorHale I wholeheartedly agree with Rhoi that you should have backups of all your important data, on any OS. If you've looked for, but not found out, how to back up the things that are cumbersome or impossible to replace--I'm thinking your Skype chat logs, probably your music, and any personal documents--I recommend posting a question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (Windows is supported there). For Skype in Windows, [logs and other personal data are in `%appdata%\Skype`](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA392/how-do-i-manage-my-conversation-history-in-skype-for-windows-desktop).