# How to change Ubuntu version from 21.04 to 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, 21.04

I am using ubuntu 21.04 version with windows 10 dual boot. I wanted to switch to the 20.04 LTS version without losing any data in windows or ubuntu partition. Is there any way to do so?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Reinstall, and overwrite the partition containing 21.04. See https://www.itechguides.com/dual-boot-ubuntu-windows-10/ and https://askubuntu.com/a/92066/124466