# How Does Wubi Work?

Tags: installation, windows, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

How does the Wubi installer work?  Which partition does it install Ubuntu on?  If it's on the Windows partition, where is it in the filesystem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation) also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/1064/what-is-wubihow-does-it-work and several other topics.

Comment: @Rinzwind That question focuses on the differences between a normal installation and a Wubi installation, while this one focuses on the technical details of Wubi.  They're not dupes at all.

Answer (score 2):

Wubi installs just like a normal "windows program". (you can  uninstall it easy to = the normal way).   It is considered by Windows as a second OS a boot time.   You have no partition - just space of Windows (on the C partition).  Windows is not able to see what is in that space.  Ubuntu can see the complete windows installation on the C-drive.  But a good advice: just try it ( as wubi no more and   not to long).  Make a specific partition for Ubuntu and install it just on that partition.  There is Gparted (you can download it for free) for making the partitions. This methode make your Ubuntu installation independent from Windows.  Good luck