# Why when I retrieve the list of partitions it only gives me one result?

Tags: windows, partitioning, wubi

When I type
`sudo fdisk -l`
it just gives me 1 partition (I have 2 partitions for Ubuntu and Windows 7).

See the full result:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320071851520 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625140335 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2b15104e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   625137663   312567808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I think this is the Windows 7 partition.

Note: I installed Ubuntu using the Wubi installer for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48425/how-does-wubi-work/48429#48429) to another (unfortunately, closed) question, the key fact you mention here is that you used Wubi to install Ubuntu. Thus, Ubuntu is installed like an additional Windows program within your Windows partition, specifically in `C:\ubuntu` (see [this guide from the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) for more information). No separate partition was created for Ubuntu at setup.