# Is Wubi completely safe?

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can wubi harm my PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61476/can-wubi-harm-my-pc)

I'm a total beginner when it comes to Operating systems and all things like that. I really love Ubuntu but I don't want to break my computer installing it. I want to install Wubi and I was wondering if It is completely safe (My computer is pretty rubbish, it needed repairing after I installed universal theme patcher).

I want Ubuntu so my computer will run quicker, that is the only reason, I am not a developer or anything like that I just love how Ubuntu looks and, runs but I want to keep windows 7.

I have a Compaq hp laptop.(I do not know the model name),

- AMD Sempron m100 processor (2.00 Ghz),
- 2 GB of RAM
- Windows 7 home premium