# Ubuntu 11.10 very slow compared to Windows

Tags: 11.10

I'm new to Ubuntu/linux. Since my PC is very old and not very fast with Windows 7, I decided to give Ubuntu a try, so I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 11.10 today. When I first started it, I had bad  800x600 resolution and it was very slow and annoying. So I installed a driver for my graphic card and now everything looks very nice (1280x1024).But I think  it's still far slower than Windows 7.

I tried to run in Ubuntu like a few people suggested on the forum but if I log in I get a black screen saying something like "this video mode cannot be displayed". I get that same screen when booting Ubuntu btw, but after about 15 seconds it disappears and just starts Ubuntu.

I also installed other drivers for my graphic card but everything stayed the same. 
I noticed that i.e. when I open Firefox or system settings it takes about 5 seconds till it opens (while Windows 7 takes under 1 second to start i.e. Chrome) and when I do this my CPU usage gets to 100% for a short time.

Computer specs:
**Memory:** 2GB RAM
**Processor:** Intel Pentium 4  2.8GHz
**Graphics Card:** Nvidia GeForce 6800 400MHz.

I read on various forums that 11.04 works flawless on many PCs, where 11.10 is very slow. Should I install 11.04 or could anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Where do you have Ubuntu installed? Is it in a partition on the same drive as Windows 7 or is it on another drive? Out of curiosity, what is `Ubuntu 2`? I'm not familiar with the reference (which may just be because I'm ignorant).

Comment: I think he must mean "Ubuntu 2D", i.e. all of the 3D effects/compositing turned off.  It's an option when you are at the login screen.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Ubuntu 2D. I installed Ubuntu on the same partition as Windows 7. Could this be the reason for being so slow?

Comment: @pestilence OK, thanks. FWIW, I think it is also commonly referred to as *Unity* 2D. @Patrick I'm still not quite clear. How did you install Ubuntu? Did you boot from a Live CD or USB? Or did you use a Windows program called `Wubi`?

Comment: I installed it using the Windows program you refer to "Wubi" as it was the easiest method for me.

Comment: @irrationalJohn Fair enough, but the default configuration in Ubuntu is to call it "Ubuntu 2D" in the lightdm dialogue.

Comment: Hi patrick! As you have installed ubuntu using WUBI you will not get true performance of ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

To get Ubuntu 2D to work, you should try running nvidia-settings to configure the X server more precisely.  Under "X Server Display Configuration", set the desired resolution instead of leaving it on auto.  Then click "Save to X configuration file" (it should be /etc/X11/xorg.conf) and reboot. Then try logging into Ubuntu 2D.

Another possible explanation is that you are feeling the performance penalty from running off a Wubi-installed partition.  See [What performance differences are there when installing with Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8159/wubi-performance-difference) for example.  To get better performance, install ubuntu directly onto a fresh partition.

Comment: I changed the resolution from auto to 1280*1024 and clicked on Apply as when I clicked on "Save to X configuration file" he couldn't find that file. Rebooted anyway and Ubuntu 2D works now, but it is hardly any faster as the normal Ubuntu :(

Comment: I've added a comment about your having installed using Wubi.