# Will ubuntu 12.04 LTS run faster when installed individually instead of in the windows folder?

Tags: installation, boot, performance, menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What performance differences are there when installing with Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8159/what-performance-differences-are-there-when-installing-with-wubi)

I have lots of freezes and stuff... So I was wondering if I installed Ubuntu individually instead of inside my windows installation, then it would perform much better. I assume that because then Ubuntu wouldn't have to navigate to it's folder all of the time. I might also be able to access folders from my hard drive as well, even with my windows installation broken. So would it perform any better if I installed it individually without using an OS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. An independent Ubuntu (dual-boot) configuration will be faster and *may* be more stable than a Windows-based (Wubi) install.

Answer (score 1):

Independent Ubuntu installation in its defined Filesystem (**EXT4**) performs much better then NTFS.

From [Wubi page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/)

> Wubi uses a virtual disk that is sensitive to forced shutdowns.
>   If Wubi becomes damaged as a result of a hard reboot, there is a
>   chance that Windows may also become corrupted since the principle
>   behind Wubi is that of a virtual disk within the host operating
>   system.

Infact this kind of Question was addressed previously , you can refer here

[What performance differences are there when installing with Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8159/wubi-performance-difference)