# Stable version of ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, lubuntu, mythbuntu

My question is simple: which edition of ubuntu is the most stable, reliable, fast and nice? And also, should I prefer Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu or Mythbuntu?

**Note:** I want it to be as fast as possible.

**Note [2]:** I will install ubuntu with wubi.

Comment: Read my answer about the Wubi usage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Ubuntu and its derivatives?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not talk about MythBuntu, because I have no experience with it, but, as far as the other three go, *they are essentially the same core operating system with a different graphical user interface*.

Ubuntu is using [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) as it's core graphical user interface experience, Lubuntu is using [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) and Kubuntu is using [KDE (The K Desktop environment)](http://www.kde.org/).

Those three are very stable, and, performance-wise, the Lubuntu variant must be the most lightweight.

**[EDIT1]:** [If I were to pick the fastest of the three, I would pick Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

**[EDIT2]:** [MythBuntu](http://www.mythbuntu.org/) seems to be a home entertainment variant of Ubuntu.

Also keep in mind, that a strong pick, when it comes to performance too, is [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) which is using [XFCE](http://xfce.org/) as its graphical user interface. Speaking from experience, I find Xfce to be lighter than LXDE and more user friendly.

Comment: By saying edition I mean 8.04, 10.04, 11.10, ect...

Comment: I would not use 8.04 it's old, and has flaws in many places, including security (passwords are stored in md5). If I were you, unless I had a production server, I would opt for the latest release each time, which is, for the time being, 12.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Usually the LTS versions are the ones with less experimenting and most refinement. I'd recommend 12.04 or 10.04. Unity was just introduced in 11.04 and still buggy so I wouldn't use that if you really really value stability.

Answer (score 0):

By experience, the latest will always be more stable. This does not count when we are talking about a very old system, but assuming the user is up to date with the hardware, the more recent the version is, the more updated it is, the more stable it is.

For each new version, there are many fixes, updates and compatibility issues attended. So it is normal to assume the latest is always better (Again, assuming the user updates his/her hardware).

Some improvements might be faster startups or cpu/memory usage, more hardware compatibility and file system enhancements, all of which add to the stable part.

Which is more recommended, depends on your needs and you hardware:

**Ubuntu** - Most tested and used. I personally recommend this one.

**Kubuntu** - More options, the interface looks similar in somes aspects to Windows (The type of menu and how/where options are.

**Lubuntu/Xubuntu** - For users with low hardware. Great speed and low cpu/memory usage.

**Mythbuntu** - If you like movies, tv series, music this is the one for you.

There are many others but again, this depend on how the user will use the system and the hardware they have.

### Note about Wubi install

If you are going to install it by Wubi then you will not achieve the fastest performance. There is an excellent question/answer [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation) and [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8159/what-performance-differences-are-there-when-installing-with-wubi) about why NOT to use Wubi if you want to avoid several odd problems and performance issues. If you still do then your Note1 will have issues with your Note2 and we don't want 2 notes angry at each other do we? ^^.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a stable and reliable os, you should use a [LTS-version](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS). The latest / current LTS-version is [Ubuntu Precise Pangolin 12.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop).

If your system should be fast, you could choose a lightweight desktop like LXDE, XFCE or another window-manager like fluxbox.