# Is ubuntu installed with wubi have some differnces from general one

Tags: 12.04, wubi

When I install Ubuntu with wubi - is it the same if I simply install it? Like disk formatting, etc? Because I need ubuntu for mongodb and need to be sure it will be work as fast as normal one.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that it is a bit slower for IO.

[What performance differences are there when installing with Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8159/what-performance-differences-are-there-when-installing-with-wubi)

...but to the best of my knowledge, wubi won't work with anything after 12.04.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2209033