# Is a Windows installation slower

Tags: 14.04, windows

Is it correct that if Ubuntu is installed inside Windows using Windows installer then it works slower?

Comment: Nothing is true unless some official source confirms it, I think...

Comment: btw, an Ubuntu installed inside Windows seems to use a file as a hard disk. Probably this hinders reading from hard.

Comment: You mean an Ubuntu permanently installed inside Windows? That doesn't make sense..

Comment: I mean wubi installer.

Comment: Yeah but after install, Ubuntu is a separate OS, right? So it's not exactly "Ubuntu inside Windows".

Comment: @Abhimanyu [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) creates a filesytem for Ubuntu on a disk image stored inside an NTFS filesystem (almost always the NTFS filesystem of an installed Windows system). So in terms of where it is stored, a Wubi system really is Ubuntu inside Windows.

Comment: Oh I see it now. I didn't know.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus The short answer is, **yes**, a Wubi Ubuntu system is slower than a comparable regular installation of Ubuntu. We may close this as a duplicate of [What performance differences are there when installing with Wubi?](http://askubuntu.com/q/8159/22949)