# How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?

Tags: apt, gnupg

I added some extra repositories with the Software Sources program. But when I reload the package database, I get an error like the following:

> W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8BAF9A6F

I know I can fix it using `apt-key` in a terminal, according to the official Ubuntu documentation. But I would have liked to do it graphically. Is there a way to do this without using a terminal?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/127326/178596

Comment: 'A mean'? Curious what you meant by that.

Comment: You can check this [SO thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308760/w-gpg-error-http-ppa-launchpad-net-precise-release-the-following-signatures/) for solution. Link to [related site](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/04/w-gpg-error-httpppalaunchpadnet-precise.html)

Comment: @MichaelScheper 'Is there a mean[s] to not to open a terminal?' =~ 'Is there a way to do it without a terminal?'

Comment: @Wilf: Oh! I don't mean to nitpick grammar, but it did confuse me. From the reference I just checked, 'means' is a singular noun, and the one you meant. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/means But if you and Agmentor are using some variant form of English where the grammar in the question is correct, I'd love to see a reference to it, just because I'm interested in that sort of thing. ☺

Comment: For users that want to remove a repository, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/43345/178596) *(that should make this comment more on-topic, though I suppose evaluating grammar is as well here :) )* @MichaelScheper It is an unusual way of saying it, but I have learnt as part of English in the UK (this probably means my English is worse than if I was taught it properly [with nouns etc]! xD). The quote [`a means to end`](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/120390/77978) comes to mind, though the issue there is the end bit, but it is where means means a method or a way.

Comment: @Wilf: The dictionary I linked to was a UK dictionary, and 'a means to end' entirely illustrates my point, which is that 'means' is singular. Therefore, 'mean' is not the right word. But you're right where you say this has gone way off topic, so I'll bow out of further discussion, and leave it to you to decide whether to edit the question. Cheers.

Comment: Here is a reliable answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/a/15272/481928

Answer (score 261, accepted):

By far the simplest way to handle this now is with Y-PPA-Manager (which now integrates the `launchpad-getkeys` script with a graphical interface).

1. To install it, first add the webupd8 repository for this program:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
   ```
2. Update your software list and install Y-PPA-Manager:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
   ```
3. Run y-ppa-manager (i.e. type `y-ppa-manager` then press enter key).
4. When the main y-ppa-manager window appears, click on "Advanced."
5. From the list of advanced tasks, select "Try to import all missing GPG keys" and click OK.

   You're done! As the warning dialog says when you start the operation, it may take quite a while (about 2 minutes for me) depending on how many PPA's you have and the speed of your connection.

Comment: fyi, while adding the repo it outputs the link webupd8.org/2010/11/y-ppa-manager-easily-search-add-remove.html for more information.

Comment: Not really useful in a webserver, as this installs X11. Don't use this method if you're on a server edition, check karthick87's answer!

Comment: sudo apt-get update produces error: W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 089EBE08314DF160

Comment: Does this allow to verify the keys which are imported, or are you simply blindly importing everything (and therefore trusting everyone who has a PPA)?

Comment: You're importing (and trusting) the keys for every PPA you've added to your system. The assumption is that you trust those PPA's and have checked them out before you added them via apt.

Comment: Does anybody happen to know what the command is that y-ppa-manager uses for its 'Advanced>Try to import all missing GPG keys'?  That is so super helpful, I would really like to make an alias of it so wouldn't have to launch y-ppa-manager if that's all I need to do.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/15272/20358) is easier **by far**, and actually requires fewer commands than this "graphical" answer.

Comment: But the question asked for a graphical method.

Comment: `y-ppa-manager` fails to "open display" on my ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Tha's wont works on most server , you were most mention this app needs `GUI` to work I waste 15 min installing it .this command from answer below is perfect  `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUBKEY>`

Comment: You'll notice that the question specifies "Is there a way to do this without using a terminal?"

Comment: @jpaugh not if you have multiple keys missing.

Comment: @vikki Actually, batch jobs is where the command-line really shines. You can do it like this: `for pubkey in Key1 Key2 Key3 ... KeyN; do sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "$pubkey"; done`. In that case, `key1`...`KeyN` is a space-separated list of public key IDs that should be imported. (The dots themselves should not be included.) The more keys you need to import, the more convenient this is, because you can let it run and walk away from it while it finishes.

Comment: @jpaugh getting the keys is the task I was thinking of as arduous. Is there a command to list the missing ones?

Comment: No, I don't. It will depend on why you need them. (Or maybe how you lost them?) I've never added more than a few ppas at a time, and can't think of a different reason to need keys.

Comment: Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.

Comment: Your fix involves using `apt-get update` which won't work because keys are missing, makes no sense

Comment: Don't, Do not install this, Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu groovy Release  404  Not Found,

Answer (score 922):

### This answer was valid for Ubuntu 20.04 and previous versions. For Ubuntu 20.10 and later versions, see [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71384057/897968).

The short version is:

```sh
sudo mkdir -m 0755 -p /etc/apt/keyrings/ 

wget -O- https://example.com/EXAMPLE.gpg |
    gpg --dearmor |
    sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/EXAMPLE.gpg > /dev/null
    sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/keyrings/EXAMPLE.gpg

echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/EXAMPLE.gpg] https://example.com/apt stable main" |
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/EXAMPLE.list
    sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/EXAMPLE.list

# Optional (you can find the email address / ID using 'apt-key list')
sudo apt-key del support@example.com
```

### Original answer:

Execute the following commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUBKEY>
```

where `<PUBKEY>` is your missing public key for repository, e.g. `8BAF9A6F`.

Then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**ALTERNATE METHOD:**

```
sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  <PUBKEY>
sudo gpg -a --export <PUBKEY> | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Note that when you import a key like this using `apt-key` you are telling the system that you trust the key you're importing to sign software your system will be using. Do not do this unless you're sure the key is really the key of the package distributor.

Comment: man how to reverse this command it make a lot of Ign and didn't work see this : http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/6885/igny.png

Comment: @Naruto That's normal. It means *that* list hasn't changed on the server.

Comment: You can simply pass `NO_PUBKEY` value as keys parameter. for example GPG error[...]NO_PUBKEY 3766223989993A70 => sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys  3766223989993A70

Comment: 8BAF9A6F <-- where did you get that number?

Comment: The number 8BAF9... is what you see in the original error. It would be something like NO_PUBKEY 8BAF...

Comment: If someone tampered with data between me and the repository, and substituted stuff they'd signed, this would wind up with me just adding the key they used, more or less blindly.  So what's the process to verify that the key is the right one?

Comment: Ultimately you are trusting the keyserver (at keyserver.ubuntu.com in the first example)

Comment: This is a great answer. Just note the the op was asking specifically for a graphical way to do this, not using the command line.

Comment: @monotasker: Indeed. I wish I'd seen this answer first, because I prefer typing over wading through a GUI any day. But to be fair, the OP did ask for a graphical method, right at the end.

Comment: For the alternate method, you don't actually have to specify the keyserver, since `gpg` has a pool of them that it trusts.

Comment: @Phil_1984_, @jpaugh: No, key servers are never trusted when using PGP. Keys are generally verified via chains of signatures of the UIDs or via manual inspection, such as comparing key IDs or fingerprints. The latter is effectively what you are doing when you use `apt-key --recv-key 3766223989993A70`: you're telling `apt-key` that you trust the key with that key ID. If the keyserver tried to return a different key, `apt-key` would not accept it in place of `3766223989993A70`.

Comment: Best solution for Ubuntu 16.04 server.

Comment: On a recent Debian Stretch I had to install the `dirmngr` package first.

Comment: Although OP asked for it graphically, I needed it for CLI and this resolved my issue.

Comment: This still works in Ubuntu 16!

Comment: The key adding works on `debian 10`. I had to add several public keys.

Comment: State on 2022.08.28 on jammy:
`Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).`

Comment: Neither of these methods is working for me. I successfully add the key, but when I do `sudo apt-get update` again, I still get the same error.

Comment: I confirm that this doesn't work in ubuntu 22.04...

Answer (score 95):

It happens when you don't have a suitable public key for a repository.

To solve this problem use this command:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9BDB3D89CE49EC21
```

which retrieves the key from ubuntu key server. And then this:

```
gpg --export --armor 9BDB3D89CE49EC21 | sudo apt-key add -
```

which adds the key to apt trusted keys.

The solution can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Authentication%20Tab) & [here](http://cultoffree.wordpress.com/2009/02/03/w-gpg-errorno_pubkey-60d11217247d1cff-wtf/) & [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150210081035/http://namhuy.net/3116/how-to-fix-gpg-error-no_pubkey-in-ubuntu.html).

Comment: If the hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com is not working use this `pgpkeys.mit.edu` server.

Comment: This answer solved my issue with  Kylin repository. The sogou pinyin input method added source to my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder, but apparently didn't import gpg key.  Good answer , simple and to the point, +1 ！

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me to solve php repository issue.

Comment: This answer  solved my update for `http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease`

Comment: and quite possible, that you have not generated the key for your system before. therefore before following the above steps use - `gpg --gen-key`  (references - http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html)

Comment: This is brilliant, simple and precise

Comment: Warning: apt-key is deprecated

Answer (score 39):

You need to get and import the key.

To get the key from a PPA, visit the PPA's Launchpad page. On every PPA page at Launchpad you will find this link (2), after clicking on 'Technical details about this PPA' (1):

[image: image 1]

Follow it and click on the key ID link (3):

[image: image 2]

Save the page, this is your key file.

---

Now it's time to import it:

- `Applications > Software Center`,
- `Edit > Software sources...`,
- Enter your password,
- Go to the `Authentication` tab and click on `Import Key File...`, finally
- Select the saved key file and click on `OK`.

Comment: Don't lost your time, see the answer bellow.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli, the question was how to add a pubkey using the GUI, *not* the terminal, so this answer was perfect.

Comment: It's *much* easier and faster now to do this with y-ppa-manager (also a gui application). See my answer below.

Comment: OK, but what if the repository is not an ubuntu ppa.  E.g. Intel run their own repository for video hardware drivers at https://download.01.org

Comment: Great step-by-step guide, thanks very much! really helpful for some one who failed to add key via `apt-key`.

Answer (score 22):

<sub>**note: As of recent versions, it is no longer considered good practice to add PPA keys to the keyring. However, I will leave this answer but apt-key is now deprecated so it is recommended we follow [different methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71384057) for now.**</sub>

apt can only handle 40 keys in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d . 41 keys and you will get the GPG error "no public key found" even if you go through all the steps to add the missing key(s).

Check to see if there are any unused keys in this file from ppa(s) you no longer use. If all are in use, consider removing some ppa(s) along with the corresponding keyfiles in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d

Furthermore, using

```
sudo apt-key adv
```

**Is considered a security risk and is not recommended** as you are "*undermining the whole security concept as this is not a secure way of recieving keys for various reasons (like: hkp is a plaintext protocol, short and even long keyids can be forged, …)*". http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195579

I believe the correct way to add missing keys (for example 1ABC2D34EF56GH78) is

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 1ABC2D34EF56GH78
gpg --export --armor 1ABC2D34EF56GH78 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: I found it easier to just delete all keys from /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d and then proceed to accepted answer http://askubuntu.com/a/386003/284664

Comment: @mchid Can you please quote a document/url that talks about this 41 keys limit ?

Comment: @SebMa The link is posted in my answer and references a bug in Debian that was impacted by this limit. Here is an anchor to the actual post within the link which mentions this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195579#post_message_12882784 I'm not sure if actual documentation exists on this but the number 40 may have been used because "40" translates to "a lot" in many different languages.

Comment: @SebMa However, the limit exists or did exist at the time of this answer and for some time after as well. I have personally experienced this 41 keys limit and have fixed it by deleting unused keys to add a new key when 40 keys already existed to avoid this error.

Comment: @SebMa Additionally, that is not to say that you will not encounter this error if you have <41 keys. You will also get this error when you have a missing key. So, **first** check to see if you have too many keys and **then** proceed to fix the problem by adding the key correctly.

Comment: @SebMa And if you want more, just google: 'gpg mailing list "40-keys"' there are many references in the results.

Comment: @mchid Thanks. One more thing, you said in your answer no to use `sudo apt-key adv` because `hkp` is a plaintext protocol, when then does your `gpg --keyserver ...` command contain this hkp url : `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80` , is it not a plaintext url too ?

Comment: @SebMa I didn't say that. The plaintext thing was only one thing mentioned in one of the posts. The alternate commands I use come from the Debian documentation.

Comment: @mchid Sorry, I didn't notice it came from the Debian documentation. Do know a more secure way to add a missing key ?

Comment: @SebMa no https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt

Comment: Warning: apt-key is deprecated

Comment: @DanielAndrzejewski Yes, thank you. I will have to update the answer later. In the meantime, you can follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71384057/3393576) as an alternative method of adding a key for a repository. Also, if you do use this other method, remember to delete the corresponding key from your keyring so that the key only applies to the single repository. The reason it is depreciated is because adding the key to your keyring applies the key to all repositories. Adding the key to a single repo in one of your sources.list files only applies to the single repository.

Comment: @DanielAndrzejewski Alternatively, if it's a PPA, you can simply delete the corresponding sources list file for the PPA in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory and then add the ppa again using the `sudo add-apt-repository` command. Adding the PPA again should automatically update the key to the newest version. The only problem with this is that it seems like it's vulnerable to the same security flaw (it adds the key to the global keyring).

Comment: @mchid my problem was related to docker-ce and containerd.io packages. Docker-ce was the latest but containerd.io package was version locked to some version not fully compatible with the latest docker-ce. When I removed versionlock and updated containerd.io package the problem got fixed.

Comment: @DanielAndrzejewski That's good. On a side note, it seems like we should be able to use apt-key to add the key and then simply move the key over to /etc/apt/keyrings to avoid the security issue and then manually link that path to the key file in the sources list file for the individual repository. Although, I have not tested this.

Answer (score 13):

There is a tiny script packaged in the WebUpd8 PPA which I'll link as a single .deb download so you don't have to add the whole PPA - which automatically imports all missing GPG keys.

Download and install [Launchpad-getkeys](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+files/launchpad-getkeys_0.3.1-1~webupd8~natty3_all.deb) (ignore the ~natty in its version, it works with all Ubuntu versions from Karmic all the way to Oneiric). Once installed, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo launchpad-getkeys
```

If you're behind a proxy, things are a bit more complicated so see [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/launchpad-getkeys-gets-proxy-support.html) for more info

Comment: It is indeed the way I do now, since I saw this program presented on your website. Nevertheless, the aim of the question was to know how to do it in a graphical way.

Comment: The launchpad-getkeys script is now integrated into the program Y-PPA-manager.  https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/y-ppa-manager

Answer (score 7):

This error can also occur when the apt list file by the PPA points to a local keyring, like

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/SOMETHING.gpg] https://download.something.org/something something/
```

And while that file may exist on your system (possibly downloaded with a prior command), it may be unreadable due to missing permissions. I just fixed this kind of error by running

```
chmod 644 /usr/share/keyrings/*
```

after having fetched the keyring file. The underlying issue was the usage of `sudo` when I already *was* root user. Really weird as all of this is root anyway and there was no access permission failure message anywhere... but that fixed it

Comment: This was also the reason why it wouldn't work for me. The GPG key instructions from Hashicorp do not work on my Ubuntu because the permissions were not set correctly. After `chmod`, `apt` finally could read the file.

Comment: I had a similar issue where the `keyrings` directory had incorrect permissions. I fixed it by running `sudo chmod 755 /etc/apt/keyrings`.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue while installing Heroku. The link below solved my problem -

http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.in/2011/08/fixing-gpg-keys-in-ubuntu.html

After fixing the `NO_PUBKEY` issue, the below issue remained

```
W: GPG error: xhttp://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG C927EBE00F1B0520 Heroku Release Engineering <release@heroku.com>
```

To fix it I executed the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo -i  
apt-get clean  
cd /var/lib/apt  
mv lists lists.old  
mkdir -p lists/partial  
apt-get clean  
apt-get update
```

Source - [Link to solve it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

Comment: I'm still getting same error, `GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid:`

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have `apt-transport-https` installed:

```
dpkg -s apt-transport-https > /dev/null || bash -c "sudo apt-get update; 
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https -y"
```

Add repository:

```
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add - 
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
```

Install Skype for Linux:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux -y
```

Source: https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Beta-signatures-couldn-t-be-verified-because-the/td-p/4645756

Answer (score 5):

More generally, the following method should work for every repository. First of all search, with eventual help of a search engine, for a text on the program provider's website looking like the following:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.1 (GNU/Linux)
[...]
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Such a text is for example displayed on http://deb.opera.com. Copy the passage, paste it in an empty file that you create on your desktop. This results in the key file.

Then continue with the importation of the key:

- Applications > Sofware Center
- Edit > Sofware sources..., enter password
- Authentication tab, click on 'Import Key File...'
- Select the saved key file and click on 'Ok'.

You may now remove the previously created key file.

Answer (score 2):

Good! I finally found the way!

I've tested all methods to fix *GPG error NO_PUBKEY* and nothing worked for me.

I've deleted the entire contents of the folder `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`

```
cd /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d
sudo rm -R *
sudo apt-get update
```

And I use the **Y-PPA-Manager** method because I'm too lazy to create all pubkey's manually (too many): http://www.unixmen.com/fix-w-gpg-error-no_pubkey-ubuntu/

run `sudo apt-get update` again and finally everything works great now! Thanks!

*Based Source :* post #17 on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1263540

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me too.  Presumably a corrupted keyfile somewhere?

Comment: this even raises more errors. Not good ans

Comment: I confirm, it's generate more errors

Comment: This doesn't work and the second line is dangerous and should be handled with care.

Answer (score 2):

Updated version (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

Because apt-key is deprecated now, and you want to use `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`, you can use

```
sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key <PUBKEY>
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings/
sudo gpg -a --export <PUBKEY> /etc/apt/keyrings/<your-keyfile-name>.gpg
# now go to your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/<source definition list file>, and 
# add [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/<your-keyfile-name>.gpg] between deb and url like this:
# deb <add here> https://...
```

`<PUBKEY>` is the 8 character fingerprint like `210976F2` and `<target name>` is a name of your choice by which you will know that key.

EDIT: Updated for more security, taken from a [lengthy answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181/309325)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181/887635 explains in detail why your answer is insecure and should not be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with DynDNS's Updater client.

Turns out it was just expired keys.

Reinstalling the software (downloading a new `.deb` from the website, then using Software Centre to reinstall) fixed the problem.

Error message for reference:

```
W: GPG error: http://cdn.dyn.com stable/ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 141943.......
```

Answer (score 0):

2021 August. This is what worked for me.

```
cd /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d
sudo rm -R *
sudo apt-get update
```

The last line will raise errors of missing keys.

What you'd then have to do is manually install each of the keys listed in the errors
for example if the error is saying that your missing `PUB_KEY` is `9BDB3D89CE49EC21`,

You can manually add the Key with the command `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 9BDB3D89CE49EC21`

Re-run sudo apt-get update

Repeat the process for the new key raised in the error

Say if the new key was `3BDB3D89CE49EC24`,
Just Manually add the Key with the command `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3BDB3D89CE49EC24`

Re-run sudo apt-get update and repeat the process until all the errors are gone.

Then go back to the package site you were trying to install and repeat the installation process.

For my case, the error was coming while I tried installing `Sublime Text`
Doing the above and returning to the Sublime installation guide [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html#apt) solved the issues.

Don't forget to upvote if this works for you. And it must do

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to check who is signing the repository by inspecting the offending file(s) in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
For example, examining the mysql.list file, it shows where the key is stored

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-apt-config
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools
#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools-preview
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0
```

As you can see, the key is stored in `/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gp`. At this point you can download the new offending key in the proper place

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys [OFFENDING KEY] && rm /usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg && gpg  --output /usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg --export [OFFENDING KEY]
```

eventually leaving away the `rm /usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg` part if you don't have the key