# Is it better to install Ubuntu as a windows application or dual boot?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

I went to the Ubuntu website and saw that you can either download Ubuntu and install it as a dual boot operating system or install it as a windows application using Wubi.

I was wondering, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using either? 
Also which one is preferred and better?

Thanks!