# Wubi vs "proper" installation"?

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

Why should a dual-booter do a "proper" ubuntu installation instead of through wubi? In other words, how is a "proper" installation better (for both, the user and ubuntu community/canonical)? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a "proper" ubuntu install i.e not the one through windows, you can easily  later remove Windows.

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus

Answer (score 1):

WUBI tends to break. A lot. I've updated my kernel before and broke it.

Another downside is say you want to use the alpha of 11.10 and you have a WUBI install on 10.10. DO NOT UPGRADE IT BREAKS IT.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi is not as great. It even broke my windows boot loader . 
What i did is installed vmplanet from vmware(it's free). and installed ubuntu as a virtual machine. now i can have best of both worlds. For people like me who just can't get rid of windows, this seems to be the best solution.