# Will wubi become one of the standard methods of installing and using Ubuntu, long-term?

Tags: wubi

Since most laptops come with preformed partitions and manufacturer recovery partition, Linux newbies like me, who are not full-time Linux users, but love its beauty & concept and want to enjoy it risk-free, find wubi as a life-saver. My question is to know if wubi will continue to be a safe and dependable way of installing and using Ubuntu, long-term.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ] to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have worded it right. Just looking for an answer to: Will wubi harm my Win 7 PC is I use it a few hrs a day, long term. Reformatting the existing partitions or disturbing a functional manufacturer's recovery partition is not an option for me! Thanks.

Comment: Please write a new question with your concern, some one is bound to answer it as I think it definitely falls within the scope of the site :) Also, this question might provide some insight - [What's the difference between a Wubi install and a regular installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

Answer (score 3):

**Wubi** (Windows Based Ubuntu Installer) is just an alternative to users that want to install Ubuntu from Windows. It is one method of installing Ubuntu, there others being Ubuntu from a LiveCD, LiveUSB, Via Network, Via cloning and any other way of installing Ubuntu.

Wubi is not a standard but a way of installing Ubuntu. And from my experience is the last one I would recommend since installing any distro inside the windows partition limits a lot of stuff and from time to time Wubi has been known to create installing/booting problems for Ubuntu in comparison to the LiveCD/LiveUSB ways of installing it which are more safe and less prone to problems.

In the long run you will still be able to use Wubi to install Ubuntu.