# Should I use wubi ubuntu 12.04 for my academic studies like writing docs, programming, etc?

Tags: wubi

I've installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS as a wubi installation in Windows 7, its running fairly well.
will Wubi installation cause any problem, will I be able to access any files created in wubi Ubuntu in windows 7?
Its said wubi is only for testing out ubuntu but what if I want to use it on a daily basis, I don't want to do partition or lose any data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have no problems with writing docs or programs in an Ubuntu Wubi installation. Als always you should frequently backup your important files on an external storage. This can easily be done when you have booted Ubuntu.

To share files with Windows however it may be better to have a shared NTFS formatted data directory that can easily be accessed from both operating systems.

Still it is also possible to [mount your Wubi file container from Windows](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/) located in `C:\ubuntu\disks\` to access data but I would only recommend to do that with read access. To do so you need to install [ext2read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) in Windows.

Note that for hibernating, and file encryption a dual boot solution may be better. Please also keep in mind that if your Windows file system gets corrupted (which could also be from malware running in Windows) you may lose your Ubuntu Wubi installation as well.

See also: [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular "alongside Windows" installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)