# How permanent can a WUBI install be?

Tags: installation, wubi

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 via WUBI to my Lenovo IdeaPad laptop. I originally wanted to dual boot with my Windows7, but the windows7/Lenovo combination is configured to take up 4 primary partitions, and my hard drive is a bit to small for a logical partition install. So I thought I would do a WUBI install before getting a larger hard drive to accommodate a larger install on logical partitions.

Question: My WUBI install is working out really nicely in fact. Everything is fast and dandy, and it out performs the windows OS already there. So, is it worth migrating to a permanent install if WUBI is as nice as this? Or will there be problems down the road?

Answer (score 0):

Wubi is less tested than normal Ubuntu installs, since a lot of people and particularly developers, do not have Windows installed. So when you use a Wubi install, it's even more important to keep backups and particularly when doing distribution upgrades.

A working Wubi install shouldn't degrade much in performance or things like that. You may want to defrag your host filesystem from time to time, but you'll probably want to do that anyway. I don't think it'll be too significant in any case.

Normally, I would recommend doing a normal install for a permanent installation, but it sounds to me like you've found a very good exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  Yes, the Wubi install works great--however, now I am wondering... if it is this good in wubi on my laptop,it must really be fast in a normal install...

Comment: There will probably be a small overhead compared to installing directly onto the disk, but it's not big. I guess, perhaps, if the Windows filesystem were highly fragmented, it might be noticeable. Large files doesn't normally fragment too much though.

Answer (score 0):

If Your Wubi install is working that great, then I don't think you need to worry about another normal installation.

As Jo-Erlend Schinstad says, You may want to defragment tools on Windows system on the Wubi partition.

As the answer of the Title: I'd say, It is permanent as permanent your Windows is and your own decision is. If you want to remove Ubuntu, it's a matter of seconds to do so from Add/Remove program. *(I myself find it less permanent, cause I have a habit of regular program removing ;P)*

You may want to check these links

- [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular "alongside Windows" installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/615/61218)
- [Official Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Yes, the Wubi install works great--however, now I am wondering... if it is this good in wubi on my laptop,it must really be fast in a normal install... – Steve

Comment: @Steve I've edited my answer with two links. You may want to check those