# Ubuntu installation inside/outside windows - which is better?

Tags: installation, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

I am aware that ubuntu can be installed on a machine in two ways keeping windows os in parallel, probably the installation is called inside windows and outside windows ? (Please correct me if I am wrong)

My question is which approach is better and why? Will there be any difference in the behavior of processes or any other change at system level?

What are the advantages/disadvantages of one approach over the other?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of windows is better because if it is inside of windows and if windows crash on you or if you don't want windows anymore than Ubuntu will not be bootable or gone.

Comment: Only a *very* small subset of problems that would keep Windows from working, will keep a Wubi system from working. Wubi only requires that the Windows system's NTFS partition be uncorrupted (or at least uncorrupted where Wubi stores its disk image), and that the Windows boot loader / boot menu are functional.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi is not great. Your Ubuntu installation will likely inherit whatever problems your Windows installation had. I installed Ubuntu via Wubi once, and it was so painfully slow I ended up completely erasing the hard drive and redoing the installation.

Comment: Windows is not actually *running* when a Wubi system runs, so Ubuntu, installed with Wubi, will *not* inherit *most* of the problems of the Windows system. If the windows system's NTFS partition is corrupted or highly fragmented, Wubi may be adversely affected by that.

Answer (score 0):

Inside/Outside should be replace with Internal/External Installation in question.
Wubi installation is fair for just try out means for a short time, you can use it. If you want to access Full features of Ubuntu, then you have to install alongside with different partition. External Installation will be Better.